# Inserting data into 2 tables that are joined by a junction table

Tags: mysql

I have a music database. One table of artists and one of songs with artist_id, and song_id in a junction table. Part of the assignment asks to INSERT 3 songs with 2 or more artists. I'm not sure of the syntax on how to enter the data. Please advise. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ Since you mention "_assignment_" is this a homework question? If so, please read the FAQ about asking / answering homework questions on this site >>> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/3711083 _ If you have written any code to solve this assignment please add it to your post. Even if it doesn't work as expected it will provide a starting point for other SO contributors to give you advice

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need 3 table here .

**1. artists**

**2. songs**

**3. artist_song**

At first insert some data to artists and songs table.

```
insert into artists(name) values ("Love me like you do")

insert into songs(name) values ("someone")
```

Then you get the primary key of songs and artists data.
reference them to your artist_song table.

```
insert into artist_song(song_id,artist_id) values (1,1)
insert into artist_song(song_id,artist_id) values (1,2)
insert into artist_song(song_id,artist_id) values (2,1)
```

**NB**: keep your primary key **AUTO_INCREMENT**

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I ended up figuring it out.

Comment: Welcome.If my solution is correct according to your scenario, accepting answer will be highly appreciated. :)